# displaying two different types of cells in cellforitem swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I have two arrays, one with Strings and one with a custom object.

I've created two different cells respectively. I've added the contents of the two arrays into a third generic array Any. I use the third array (combinedArray) in cellForItem.

```
var customObjectArray: [customObject] = []
var stringArray = [String]()
var combinedArray = [Any]()

if combinedArray[indexPath.row] is CustomObject {


        cell1.LabelName.text = customObjectArray[indexPath.row].caption
        cell1.iconView.image = customObjectArray[indexPath.row].icon
        return cell1 
} else {

       let stringName = stringArray[indexPath.row]
       cell2.LabelName.setTitle(stringName for: UIControlState())
       return cell2
    }
```

let's say customObjectArray has 13 objects and stringObjectArray has 17 objects. I want a separate counter for each array so that it populates them correctly. The way it's working now:

the combinedArray populates all of one type first (i.e. 13 customObjectArray first), then the next type second (i.e 17 stringObjects). The order the combined array isn't necessarily important as I will probably shuffle things around at some point before getting to cellforitem. So when cellforItem goes through the first 13 objects, indexpath.row = 14, and when it gets to the second type of object, it's skipping the first 13 objects and displaying stringObject's 14th element (obviously).

I can't figure out how to start at the beginning of the second array instead of indexPath.row's current position.

I might be totally off base here and likely should be using two sections or something to that nature, but I'm relatively new to iOS dev, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: you must use combinedArray data only for both the cell types. cell.LabelName.text = stringObjectArray[indexPath.row].labelName why using stringObjectArray here use combinedArray only.

Comment: You should really do two sections.  It's really quite easy to do.

Comment: I thought about this, but I want a view that alternates b/w the two different cells in the same section. having two sections seems like it won't work for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to enclose the different data types in an enum and add all the data to your combined array in whatever order you would like.

```
enum DataHolder {
    case stringType(String)
    case customType(CustomObject)
}

var combinedArray: [DataHolder]
```

This gives you a single type for the data and a way to distingue between the cell types.

Inside of the `cellForItem` perform a switch on the combinedArray

```
switch combinedArray[indexPath.row] {
    case .stringType(let stringValue):
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StringCell", for: indexPath) as! StringObjectCell
        cell.labelName.text = stringValue
    case .customType(let customData):
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomObjectCell
        cell.labelName.text = customData.caption
        cell.iconView.image = customData.icon
```

Answer (score 1):

Use always only one array with a more specific type than `Any`

Create a protocol including all properties and functions both types have in common for example

```
protocol CommonType {
   var labelName : String { get }
   // var ...
   // func 
}
```

and make the types adopt the protocol.

Then declare the single array with that type to be able to add both static types

```
var commonArray = [CommonType]()
```

In `cellForItem` determine the cell type by conditional downcasting the type

```
let common = commonArray[indexPath.row]
if common is CustomObject {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomObject", for: indexPath) as! CustomObjectCell
   cell.LabelName.text = common.labelName
   return cell
} else {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Other", for: indexPath) as! OtherCell
   cell.LabelName.text = common.labelName
   return cell
}
```

`indexPath` math is cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: this makes sense, however, the two objects don't share any properties. i've updated my question to show a more accurate version of my code. thanks for the help!

Comment: Common properties are not required necessarily, an empty umbrella protocol is sufficient but then you always have to check and cast the type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 2 different types of data in your `UITableView` you can simply create a wrapping `enum` whose cases will represent the type. By the case you will always know how to configure the cell.

Example:
Let's say you need to show Facebook posts in your `UITableView` and there are 3 types of posts: text, image and video. Your `enum` would like this:

```
enum Post {
  case text(String)
  case image(URL)
  case video(URL)
}
```

Simple enough, right?
You need to have your `UITableViewCell` subclasses for each type of data (or single and configure it properly, but I recommend to have separate for many reasons).

Now all you need to do is keep array of `Post`s and in your `UITableViewDataSource` construct the cell you need.

```
let post = self.posts[indexPath].row
switch post {
  case .text(let text):
    let cell = // dequeue proper cell for text
    // configure the cell
    cell.someLabel.text = text
    return cell
  case .image(let url):
    let cell = // dequeue proper cell for image
    // configure the cell
    cell.loadImage(url)
    return cell
  case .video(let url):
    let cell = // dequeue proper cell for video
    // configure the cell
    cell.videoView.contentURL = url
    return cell
}
```